# Create Secret Channel in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that when sees a command with a game's name in it, gives you a role that says currently playing and makes a private channel which can only be accessed by those who have the finished role and the person who entered the command
This is my code so far-

```py
@bot.command(name= 'playfata')
async def playfata(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    _reading = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Currently Reading")
    finished = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Finished Reading")
    if _reading in member.roles:
        await ctx.reply("You are already reading The House In Fata Morgana")
    if finished in member.roles:
        await ctx.reply("You have already finished playing The House In Fata Morgana")
    else:
        await member.add_roles(_reading)
        await ctx.reply("You are now playing The House In Fata Morgana"
                        "\nHope you enjoy your playthrough!")
        overwrites = {
        discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Currently Reading"): discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Finished Reading"): discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="The Mansion's Residents"): discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="The Servants"): discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        member : discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)}
        x = ctx.author
        fatachannel= (x,'-plays-fata')
        channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(fatachannel, overwrites=overwrites)
```

The role assignment works but the channel creation does not, this is the error-

```
Ignoring exception in command playfata:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\luvya\PycharmProjects\fatamorganabot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/luvya/PycharmProjects/fatamorganabot/main.py", line 63, in playfata
    channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(fatachannel, overwrites=overwrites)
  File "C:\Users\luvya\PycharmProjects\fatamorganabot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 948, in create_text_channel
    data = await self._create_channel(name, overwrites, ChannelType.text, category, reason=reason, **options)
  File "C:\Users\luvya\PycharmProjects\fatamorganabot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 844, in _create_channel
    'id': target.id
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\luvya\PycharmProjects\fatamorganabot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\luvya\PycharmProjects\fatamorganabot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\luvya\PycharmProjects\fatamorganabot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: On what line does the error occur? I don't see you using `.id` anywhere?

Comment: I'll edit it with the full traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correct, your traceback doesn't quite represent the error.
You're trying to create a channel with a tuple of non-sense values. *Why do you need your `author` as parameter?*

I'm guessing you want the author's name in the channel-name?

You should then create the channel via

```py
channelname = ctx.author.name + "-plays-fata"
channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name = channelname, overwrites = overwrites)
```

---

```py
@bot.command(name= 'playfata')
async def playfata(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    _reading = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Currently Reading")
    finished = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Finished Reading")
    if _reading in member.roles:
        await ctx.reply("You are already reading The House In Fata Morgana")
    if finished in member.roles:
        await ctx.reply("You have already finished playing The House In Fata Morgana")
    else:
        await member.add_roles(_reading)
        await ctx.reply("You are now playing The House In Fata Morgana"
                        "\nHope you enjoy your playthrough!")
        overwrites = {
        discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Currently Reading"): discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Finished Reading"): discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="The Mansion's Residents"): discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="The Servants"): discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        member : discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)}
        channelname = ctx.author.name + "-plays-fata"
        channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name = channelname, overwrites = overwrites)
```

Comment: I replaced my code with yours, still the same error

Comment: Ah, I looked up the source code of discord.py and it looks like at least one of your role-objects is `None`. Make sure the roles `Currently Reading`, `Finished Reading`, `The Mansion's Residents` and `The Servants` exist and are spelled correctly. Make sure that all of them aren't `None`

Comment: thanks! I guess I am just dumb enough to make the same mistake twice in a row, well thankfully none of it was in the actual code tho.